# Why can't my mat checkbox update the correct value?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

in my app I'm using a `BehaviourSubject` which I toggle value to update a `MatCheckbox`. only problem is that the value doesn't get updated to the correct value, in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-udeg7m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) the value of `isChecked` is supposed to be setted instantely to false each time I check the checkbox but the value don't get updated on the checkbox.

I've been looking over internet without seeing an answer to my case

**EDIT:**

for the moment I've been able to achieve what I want by adding `setTimeout(() => this.isChecked = false, 500)` in the `subscribe` method.

Comment: It's unclear what the expected behavior is. Maybe that `if (bool)` check is breaking something for you?

Answer (score 2):

I check your code, you are updating `isChecked` value twice, one inside the `change()` method & second inside the `subscribe()` method, what kind of implementation you have done so far, it's working fine with respect to that.

Now what you want try to achieve? please let me know! If your intension is just to update the `isChecked` value, then `change()` is enough for that,

Comment: I would like to set it to false directly after checking it. the value in the console shozs false but not on my checkbox. may thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is your same code with some changes, working:

[StackBlitzSolutionWorking](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7fa87b?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Basically, I did change the html:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked" (change)="change($event)">Hello</mat-checkbox>
```

and in TS:

```
import { MatCheckboxChange } from '@angular/material/checkbox/checkbox';
...

change(event: MatCheckboxChange) {
    this.isChecked = event.checked;
    this.test.bool.next(this.isChecked);
  }

  constructor(private test: TestService) {
    this.test.bool.subscribe(bool => {
      console.log('this.isChecked:', this.isChecked);
      console.log('bool:', bool);
      // if (bool) this.isChecked = false;
    });
  }
```

The problem was that with the sentence 'if (bool)' **isChecked** always was 'false': when the check wasn't checked, it was false, and when the check was checked, as bool===true, it turned into false as well.

Comment: the behaviour I wanted was to set it to false when checking it so my console log was ok.My problem is the checkbox isn't reflecting the false state.

Answer (score 0):

Log the event in the function you're calling. The subscribe is setting it to false.

> ```
> import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
> import { TestService } from './test.service';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-app',
>   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
>   providers: [TestService]
> })
> export class AppComponent {
>   isChecked = false;
>
>   constructor(private test: TestService) {
>   }
>
>   name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
>
>   get bool(){
>     return this.test.bool
>   }
>
>   change(value){
>     this.isChecked = value;
>     console.log(this.isChecked);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: that is the desired behaviour

Comment: @JSmith then set it to false after it's changed and logged.

Comment: I may have benn unclear. I set to false automatically after I try changing the value. Normally I'd expect to show a false state on the checkbox no matter what. Here the check box toggle between the two value not showing systematically the false state. Thank in advance. btw I've managed to make it work by using `setTimeout` but if you have another solution I would prefer.